# How to add bins without interrupting edges in an histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bin, binning

[image: Problem is attached here.Kindly go through it through this link]

I tried to modify the histogram such that the binning number(height) of the original histogram should be greater or equal to 3, if the binning number is not greater or equal to three then add those consecutive bins. But I am unable to plot the modified histogram.

Comment: Please do not post handwritten images. They are not searchable via search engines and are also harder to read than digital typography. The drawn diagrams are fine if you have no other choice, but not the text.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the histogram values via `np.histogram(...)`.  And then loop through the values and bin edges to draw the combined bars one by one:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 20)
values, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(np.floor(x.min()), x.max() + 1))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5), sharey=True)

bars = ax1.bar(bins[:-1], values, width=np.diff(bins), align='edge', facecolor='skyblue', edgecolor='black')
ax1.bar_label(bars, label_type='center', fontsize=20)

left = bins[0]
current_sum = 0
for val, right in zip(values, bins[1:]):
    current_sum += val
    if current_sum >= 3 or right == bins[-1]:
        bar = ax2.bar(left, current_sum, width=right - left, align='edge', facecolor='skyblue', edgecolor='black')
        ax2.bar_label(bar, label_type='center', fontsize=20)
        left = right
        current_sum = 0
ax2.tick_params(labelleft=True)

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(np.floor(bins[0]), bins[-1] + 1))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with combined bars]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been trying to apply this program in my excel sheet data (ln(x)) which has specified values instead of random numbers. Can you tell me how to proceed. Please find attached the link for the excel sheet- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W-286VqNtIvOSJxCLAJox_ve_GRiEhWX8iwMYKDrOiw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Note that you are supposed to show serious effort to your programming problem.  Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service.

Comment: If your real data is very different from your current example data, you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71697658/edit) your post and add some new test data that are more similar.

Comment: This is good, just not sure why OP wants to sum the combined bins. Seems like it would make more sense to average the combined bins.